# Spartacus page Id not resolved after changes from smartedit

Tags: spartacus-storefront, smartedit

I have setup Commerce cloud 2005 with spartacussampledata add-on as described on https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud-2005/

Local spartacus mystore using ^3.0.3 is also setup.

Smartedit is working fine and is able to load the storefront - however adding/modifying page content (E.g., new CMS paragraph component) does not refresh the current page in smartedit. You have to refresh the browser to see changes.

Console shows error log: https://localhost:9002/occ/v2/electronics-spa/cms/pages/$%7Bid%7D?code=homepage&lang=en&curr=USD&cmsTicketId=647840012101272040605dac-11b2-4888-b410-677b1862c3a9&pageLabelOrId=homepage&pageType=ContentPage    **zone-evergreen.js:2845**
The response message from server is No page with id [${id}] found.

Is this a known bug? What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like there is an issue open with a similar description https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/11848